# Scan a webpage for an API

Tags: html, api

I would like to perform a scan of a webpage and somehow discover if the site provides an API of sorts - either XML or JSON.

For example, a webpage with the TV schedule. I want to scan example.com and find out IF it provides some sort of API with the TV schedule.

Comment: I would suggest this is next to impossible - most websites would not even reference the API (except RSS / Atom)

Comment: You can look for feeds (Atom, RSS) in the head of the document (as this is probably the only *standardized API* that there is). Other than that I guess you'll have a hard time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this is **not possible**.

I suggest looking for a RSS or Atom feed. You could also contact support, or look for documentation provided by example.com about any API's.

**Bottom Line:** If they wanted you to know about their API, they would tell you about by providing documentation, links, Wiki's etc.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that this is **impossible**.

Most websites I know of don't even reference the API (except RSS/Atom).

You can find Atom and RSS feeds in the `<head>` of the webpage.

If it's just *one* website that you want to find an API of, then you could just contact the site instead of using a script or something.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a standard way - however if there's an API that's being used on the page to drive Ajax views then you may well be able to get some information from analysis of the Javascript that's referenced on the page - it'll typically be pointing back at the API.

It goes without saying that it might well not be a "supported" API and you'd be violating terms of use using it - so it may get removed / changed / blocked without notice.